# Como guardar datos de inputs de un Activity al pasar a otra activity y enviarlos en un email?

Tags: java, android

[image: MainActivity de mi aplicacion]

Como ven en la imagen, mi MainActivity es simple, con EditTexts que el usuario debe completar, en los botones flotantes, el de check, cumple una funcion que envia el email con los datos cargados, eso funciona bien. Ahora, el boton flotante con icono de agregar, tendria que abrir la misma pantalla con los inputs vacios, y al apretar el boton de enviar, se deberian enviar en el email tanto los datos cargados en la primera pantalla y en la segunda pantalla.

Comment: La pregunta es, cada que le de al boton de agregar me va a abrir una activity nueva???, es decir si llene la data en mi main y luego le doy click 10 veces me va a abrir 10 veces la nueva activity?

Comment: no es esa la finalidad, sino que al apretar el boton de agregar simplemente limpies los campos, ya que es el mismo activity, pero, que los datos agregados por el usuario en el primer activity ya se queden guardados para enviarlos en el email.

Comment: ok ya entendi, podrias usar `SharedPreferences`para ir almacenando los datos temporalmente antes de hacer el envío del email, por otro lado, esta el asunto de almacenar el mismo campo varias veces, se me ocurre generar un objeto Json y almacenarlo como string en las preferencias temporales e irle agrenado elementos a medida que se generen antes de enviarlos por email. Tambien podrias ir utilizando una base de datos sqlite para el almacenamiento temporal, una vez enviado el email, eliminar la data de la base

Comment: **Hola, Harles, agrega lo que has intentado, por favor, te he sugerido en varias ocasiones realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pasar datos entre activities puedes usar los **intents**.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundoActivity.class);
intent.putString("obra", obra.getText().toString();
.... //repites el proceso con todos los datos que quieras pasar al segundo activity
startIntent(intent) ;
```

En el segundo **activity** los recoges

```
if (getIntent().getExtras=!null){
String obra = getIntent().getExtras.getString("obra")
.... Repites con el resto de datos que deseas recoger 
}
```

Eso es lo que puedo entender que necesitas, si es otra tu necesidad podrías explicarnos de una forma un poco más clara, ya que ko puedo entender bien tu problema. Recuerda que "obra" sería un keyValue. Espero haber ayudado en algo, como te digo si tu problema es otro, podías detallar nos de mejor forma el problema.

Saludos

Comment: esta respuesta ya se encuentra en el sitio "como enviar valores entre activities", además existen muchos ejemplos, lo que necesita el OP es enviar los datos desde los TextViews